# Wordpress set featured image pagination is required, bcz all the images are loading at a time which taking lot of time

Tags: php, wordpress, image, pagination, media

Currently I am using wordpress 3.9 version, In admin panel when I click on the 'set featured Image' while posting a new post. Then it showing media library photos, the problem is there is not pagination for the images so that all the images are loading at a time.... which is taking  lot of time.... and I have more than 1000 images in my media.

I found the pagination is available for older version of wordpress admin panel..... can some 1 check the issue suggest me plugins or any code editing in wordpress admin.

Thank You, In advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you solved this problem? BTW: nice name.